# I want to have both text and figure in same page using achemso package. Is it possible?

Tags: achemso

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcld,manuscript=letter]{achemso}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\title{Supporting Information}
\newpage
\begin{document}



%% Snapshots of mixture simulation at various times 

\center\Large \textbf{Simulation A5 : Mixture of $\alpha$ \& $\beta$ aspartyl in 1:2 ratio}

\begin{figure}[h!]

\begin{center}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{./supporting_info/mixture/snapshot_0ns}}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{./supporting_info/mixture/snapshot_250ns}}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{./supporting_info/mixture/snapshot_500ns}}\\

\end{center}

\caption{Snapshots showing the protein and the ligands (CPK representation) around it at various times of the simulation}

\end{figure}

\newpage

\center\Large \textbf{Simulation A3, Ligand : $\alpha$-aspartyl}

\begin{figure}[h!]

\begin{center}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]
{./supporting_info/alpha_aspartyl/snapshot_alpha_0ns}}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{./supporting_info/alpha_aspartyl/snapshot_alpha_250ns}}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{./supporting_info/alpha_aspartyl/snapshot_alpha_520ns}}\\
\caption{Snapshots from the simulation A3 at 0, 250 and 520 ns}

\end{center}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

By running this script I am getting two separate pages of text and after that two pages of figures.

Is there any way to get the figure right after the next?

Comment: please use `example-image` as the image so people can run the example and see the issue, as it is it is impossible to run it and see where the float goes.  Note that `\center` should be `\centering` or `\begin{center}`, the form `\center` should never be used in a document it is just half the implementation of the `center` environment. Also `[h!]` usually generates a warning and is changed to `ht`  is there a reason that you are preventing the figure being placed above text by removing the default possibility of `t` for a top float?

Comment: Yeah, I need the text to be top of the figure, it's like a heading. Thank you

Comment: But the problem is the text and the first figure were too close even I give \bigskip command. Is there any way to avoid it. I even tried using \vspace{}, reducing the size of images, but it didn't work. Thank you

Comment: Spacing between lines does the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Place the text inside the `figure` environment.

```latex
\documentclass[journal=jpcld,manuscript=letter]{achemso}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Somewhere}
\email{A@S}

\begin{document}

%% Snapshots of mixture simulation at various times 

\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering\Large

\textbf{Simulation A5: Mixture of $\alpha$ \& $\beta$ aspartyl in $1{:}2$ ratio}

\bigskip

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}

\bigskip

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}

\bigskip

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{Snapshots showing the protein and the ligands (CPK representation) 
around it at various times of the simulation}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]